# JAXB Namespace translation in a AXIS2 WebService application on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jaxb, tomcat7, apache-axis, xjc

I've used xjc of jaxb 2.2.6 to generate a set of classes from a xsd file.
By editing "package-info.java" I've associated to the different namespaces the prefix value.
So I've created a Test Class with a main that Unmarshal an xml file, edit some information, and marshal the object in xml format.
Everything works like a charm and javax.xml.bind.Marshaller object match correctly namespace and prefix as defined in package-info.

When I deploy this application as WS using axis2 on tomcat7 in the same machine and call a ws method that execute the code described above javax.xml.bind.Marshaller create an xml file with default namespace (ns1, ns2....).

The package-info.java that I've used is something like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "....", 
        xmlns = {   
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "....", prefix = "myprefix"),
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "...", prefix = "myprefix2"),
            },
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package ....;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

This is a piece of right output (This output is obtained when I execute the code as "Java Application"):

```
.....
    <ContactInformation>
        <rm:ContactDescription>ASD</rm:ContactDescription>
        <rm:ContactRole>ASD</rm:ContactRole>
        <rm:ContactLocation/>
        <rm:AdditionalContactInformation>
            <xnl:PartyName>
                <xnl:PersonName>
                    <xnl:NameElement xnl:ElementType="FirstName">ASD</xnl:NameElement>
                    <xnl:NameElement xnl:ElementType="LastName">ASD</xnl:NameElement>
                </xnl:PersonName>
                <xnl:OrganisationName>
                    <xnl:NameElement>ASD</xnl:NameElement>
                </xnl:OrganisationName>
            </xnl:PartyName>
        </rm:AdditionalContactInformation>
    </ContactInformation>
......
```

This is a piece of wrong output (This output is obtained when I execute the code inside an "Axis2/Tomcat7 WS Application"):

```
.....
  <ContactInformation>
        <ns2:ContactDescription>ASD</ns2:ContactDescription>
        <ns2:ContactRole>ASD</ns2:ContactRole>
        <ns2:ContactLocation/>
        <ns2:AdditionalContactInformation>
            <ns7:PartyName>
                <ns7:PersonName>
                    <ns7:NameElement ns7:ElementType="FirstName">ASD</ns7:NameElement>
                    <ns7:NameElement ns7:ElementType="LastName">ASD</ns7:NameElement>
                </ns7:PersonName>
                <ns7:OrganisationName>
                    <ns7:NameElement>ASD</ns7:NameElement>
                </ns7:OrganisationName>
            </ns7:PartyName>
        </ns2:AdditionalContactInformation>
    </ContactInformation>
......
```

For each case exists a package-info.java where namespaces translation are declared.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is not required to use the prefixes as defined in the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  The prefixes are used are not significant, and the namespace qualification between JAXB (JAX-WS) implementations will be the same although the prefixes may be different.

Comment: The problem is that an operation of marshalling from an object created with jaxb works differently if the application runs as "Java Application" or "Web Service Application", on axis2/tomcat7 context.
In the second case the namespaces translation doesn't work.

Comment: @f0rb1dd3n403 - Can you post the two different outputs you are getting?

Comment: @f0rb1dd3n403 - If `rm` points to the same namespace as `ns2`, and `xnl` points to the same namespace as `ns7` then the XML documents have the same namespace qualification.  The prefixes supplied in the `@XmlSchema` are only hints and need not be used.

Comment: yes, Rm points to the same namespace of Ns2, and it's the same for the others prefixes.
I agree with you that prefixes are only hints but I will have to found a way to use my custom prefixes with something different from package-info method. I don't understand why this method doesn't work in web service context. Do you have some idea? Thank you.

Comment: @f0rb1dd3n403 - It's not that the namespace prefixes aren't preserved in the web service context. Instead it's that prefixes aren't preserved by the JAXB impl leveraged by the JAX-WS implementation. Is it just aesthetic reasons you want a specific prefix?

Comment: Nope. Is necessary perform namespace translation because these xml documents are passed in input in a web service method. 
After it will return the same documents with some field modified.
For this reason is necessary that the client receive an xml document conform to the original.
Unfortunately are design choices.